# Is there a better way of debugging OpenGL than calling glGetError after each command?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm experimenting with some OpenGL on Android, and I don't have any previous experience with 3D programming. So obviously I made quite a few mistakes in my program.

When I encountered a problem and found that `glGetError` produced an error code, I just added calls to `glGetError` after each call to an OpenGL command in my drawing code. While this worked and I found my errors this way, my drawing code is now twice as big and harder to read in my opinion.

Is there a way to get rid of all these explicit calls to `glGetError` and just call it automatically? Preferably, my app should just abort with an error indicating which command is responsible if an OpenGL error occurs.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 4.2 Android offers an option called "Enable OpenGL traces" in the phone's developer options. If you set this to "Call stack on glGetError" you'll get an output like

```
07-15 15:44:43.045: D/libEGL(14251): [glEnableClientState] 0x500
07-15 15:44:43.068: D/CallStack(14251): glGetError:glEnableClientState#00  pc 00019388  /system/lib/libEGL.so
07-15 15:44:43.076: D/CallStack(14251): glGetError:glEnableClientState#01  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
07-15 15:44:43.076: D/CallStack(14251): glGetError:glEnableClientState#02  pc 0004d410  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+395)
07-15 15:44:43.076: D/CallStack(14251): glGetError:glEnableClientState#03  pc 000276e4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

in the log. In this case, I was passing a wrong enum / int to `glEnableClientState()` to trigger the error. Note that the error will be "consumed" by enabling this option and further `glGetError()` checks will not report this anymore. Instead, you can now save the time putting `glGetError()` calls in your code and just grep the log output for "glGetError:".

Comment: JIC, "Enable OpenGL traces" came in 4.2... :)

Comment: I'm not able to find "Enable OpenGL traces" on Oreo. Any ideas why they are gone?

Answer (score 3):

On OpenGL ES you cannot do much better, if you are targeting OpenGL ES 2.0 you should also be using some vendor tools (depending on your reference/target device) to aid you in shader development and performance tuning.

You **must call glError in a loop**, for example in java:

```
public void checkGLError(String op) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e("MyApp", op + ": glError " + error);
    }
}
```

But leaving production code with those check is a bad idea, glError is slow. Best option is to encapsulate inside a logging class that disables glError unless an error was found in the previous frame.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop OpenGL 4.3+ has extended debugging and callback functionalities (though I don't have any experience with those). But in ES there isn't really anything better. Sadly the best solution is still to not write any `glGetError`s (or maybe only at some selected important points, like the end of each frame or something) and only introduce them en masse when something *"doesn't work"*.

Other than that you could also make some wrapper like

```
template<typename F> void checked(F fn)
{
    fn();
    auto error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR)
        throw std::runtime_error("OpenGL error: "+std::to_string(error));
}

...
checked([&]() { glDrawElements(...); });
```

(assuming C++11, but other languages should have similar facilities)

But I think such solutions still cannot be made perfectly equivalent to no `glGetError`s at all, regarding readability and conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach to this called AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). I had some experience with it in C# in the past (some 7 years back) with SpringFramework and PostSharp. This approach extensively use code injection techniques.

So when I faced this issue (tracing GL errors) it appeared as a classic problem for AOP. Since code injection introduces some performance penalties, I assume this change (enabling of GL logging) as temporal and will keep it in a git patch for the cases where I want to use it.

1) First, alter your gradle build scripts: 
In top-level build script add this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.uphyca.gradle:gradle-android-aspectj-plugin:0.9.14'
```

In app-level script add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.uphyca.android-aspectj'
```

This will enable aspectj plugin in gradle. This project (hosted here: https://github.com/uPhyca/gradle-android-aspectj-plugin) seems deprecated now, but it is working. You can look to a newer version here: https://github.com/HujiangTechnology/gradle_plugin_android_aspectjx. For my needs (basic java code weaving) the old version worked well.
Rebuild to find if you have any issues.

2) Add our annotation which we'll use later to mark methods we want our aspect to be applied to:

```
package com.example.neutrino.maze;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Created by Greg Stein on 7/18/2016.
 */

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface GlTrace {
}
```

3) Add our Aspect:

```
package com.example.neutrino.maze;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.util.Log;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

/**
 * Created by Greg Stein on 7/18/2016.
 */
@Aspect
public class GlTraceAspect {

    private static final String POINTCUT_METHOD =
            "execution(@com.example.neutrino.maze.GlTrace * *(..))";

    private static final String POINTCUT_CONSTRUCTOR =
            "execution(@com.example.neutrino.maze.GlTrace *.new(..))";

    @Pointcut(POINTCUT_METHOD)
    public void methodAnnotatedWithGlTrace() {}

    @Pointcut(POINTCUT_CONSTRUCTOR)
    public void constructorAnnotatedWithGlTrace() {}

    @Around("methodAnnotatedWithGlTrace() || constructorAnnotatedWithGlTrace()")
    public Object weaveJoinPoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
        String className = signature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
        String methodName = signature.getName();

        // Before method execution
        // -- nothing --

        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        // After method execution
        Log.d(className, buildLogMessage(methodName));

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Create a log message.
     *
     * @param methodName A string with the method name.
     * @return A string representing message.
     */
    private static String buildLogMessage(String methodName) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        int errorCode = GLES20.glGetError();
        message.append("GlState[");
        message.append(methodName);
        message.append("]: ");

        if (GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR != errorCode) {
            message.append("ERROR:");
        }

        message.append(GLU.gluErrorString(errorCode));
        return message.toString();
    }
}
```

4) Mark methods or constructors which execute GL code with @GlTrace annotation:

```
...
    @GlTrace
    public GlEngine(int quadsNum) {
...
    @GlTrace
    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
...
```

Now after all this done, just rerun the project in AndroidStudio. You will have the following output:

```
07-18 12:34:37.715 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[<init>]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.715 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[draw]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.733 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[<init>]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.735 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[draw]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.751 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[<init>]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.751 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[draw]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.771 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[<init>]: no error
07-18 12:34:37.771 19167-19187/com.example.neutrino.maze D/GlEngine: GlState[draw]: no error
```

In my project I have only two methods with GL calls: draw method and the constructor of GlEngine class.

After you play a bit with this and get those annoying "no error" messages you can do some improvements:
0) Print errors only
1) monitor all methods which match gl* (all OpenGl methods).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Check glDebugMessageCallback

```
void GLAPIENTRY
MessageCallback( GLenum source,
                 GLenum type,
                 GLuint id,
                 GLenum severity,
                 GLsizei length,
                 const GLchar* message,
                 const void* userParam )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "GL CALLBACK: %s type = 0x%x, severity = 0x%x, message = %s\n",
           ( type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : "" ),
            type, severity, message );
}


// During init, enable debug output
glEnable ( GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT );
glDebugMessageCallback( MessageCallback, 0 );
```

Comment: This function available in OpenGl 4.3+, which is, AFAIK,  not ported to Android. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml

Comment: It is available as an extension and used in xf86-video-hwcomposer code.